# Do Docker memory limits set from within a docker-compose file take precedence over the settings defined in the Docker GUI?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Disclaimer: I know next to nothing about Docker

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513

Following this thread, it seems as though I'm doing things correctly in my v2 docker-compose file.

```
version: "2"
services:
  a:
    mem_limit: 5000000000
    mem_reservation: 5000000000
```

But I'm getting a memory allocation error when I run `docker compose run`.

I've alleviated this error in my Docker GUI settings:

[image: Docker Memory Settings]

But because of the distributed nature of my project, I need these settings to live on my docker-compose file.

1. Is there something wrong with how I've configured my docker-compose file?
2. If not, does the docker-compose file take precedence over any settings configured in the GUI? I've reduced the GUI settings back to the default 2Gb to try and determine if the docker-compose settings are ruling out, so I'm not sure if the error is due to the GUI settings, or an issue in my compose file.

Comment: The GUI configures the resources your docker VM gets, docker-compose configures resources any individual container can use of that maximum provided by the VM.

Comment: Stop using the UI. It's incredibly non-standard and confusing. It should only be used for configuring docker to run with wsl (if you're using windows that is, if you're using a mac, buy a windows machine instead).